# Execute C# Function and Postback from JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a JavaScript function that is called when a radWindow is closed like so:

```
   function OnClientCloseSecure(oWnd, args) {
       var arg = args.get_argument();

       if (arg) {
           var ResultCode = arg.ResultCode;
           var AuthCode = arg.AuthCode;
           var ReferenceNumber = arg.ReferenceNumber;
           var TransactionID = arg.TransactionID;
           var ErrorCode = arg.ErrorCode;
           var ErrorDescription = arg.ErrorDescription;
           var CardNumber = arg.CardNumber;
           var PONumber = arg.PONumber;

           __doPostBack();
       }
   }
```

I also have a C# function called `GetComplete()`. I want to make it so when the JavaScript function above is called it executes the C# function `GetComplete()` and does a PostBack so the results will be displayed. Is this possible to do with JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: @Boo Telerik radWindow http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: do you need to do a post back?  (what are you displaying your results in?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mark Up

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" style="display:none;" OnClick="Btn_Click"/>
```

This button will be hidden. It will be useful to perform a click and in code behind call the function in it's handler. Now in the handler write the code to call your c# method.

### Java Script

Perforing the click of hidden button.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function PerformClick() {
        document.getElementById('<%=btn.ClientID %>').click();
    }
</script>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetComplete();
}
```